# Can you use a constructor in Child Activity to change Parent Activity String variable?

Tags: android, android-activity, constructor, super

I have a Parent Activity class that all my Child Activity classes extend from. 
This parent activity has a field called 'activity_Id' that is a String and defaults to be null.

In the onCreate of the Parent Activity, I need to check if that field has a value, which it would only get from the Child Activity if it does I do some other logic in the onCreate of the parent activity.

Note, that each activity has a unique 'activity_Id' that it is used to alter the other logic that is being done.

Here is the ParentActivity:

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity{
    protected String activity_Id = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(activity_Id != null)
            //DO OTHER LOGIC UNIQUE TO THIS STRING ID
    }
}
```

Here is the ChildActivity:

```
public class ChildActivity extends ParentActivity{

    public ChildActivity(){
        super();
        activity_Id = "Foo123";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

This activity_Id String is predetermined but does not match the Activities name so I can not do

```
this.getClass().getName()
```

in my ParentActivity class.

This seems like the cleanliness way BUT there seems to be some taboo around using constructors in activities so I just want to make sure I do not break anything. Or if someone can think of a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: The taboo is just b/c an `Activity` is not guaranteed to be freshly constructed before each `onCreate()`. You can do things this way, but it's not clear why you wouldn't just give the subclass a custom `onCreate()` implementation: If all `ChildActivities` are `Foo123` activities, but not all `ParentActivity` subclasses are `Foo123` activities, then just put the `Foo123` logic in the subclass `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with abstract class because constructor don't construct an activity directly.

Try it like this

```
public abstract class ParentActivity extends Activity{
    protected abstract String activityId();
    .....
}
```

Then in child activity override `activityId()` with required value. And now you can compare `activityId()` in `ParentActivity` `onCreate(...)` method.

Comment: This solution works. This allows me to define the String in the ChildActivity class then reference it in the `onCreate` of the ParentActivity with the method call, removing the use of the constructor: